# '[Task]?' is not convertible to 'Optional<[Any]>'

Tags: swift, generics, types, type-conversion, option-type

I've made extension

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == [Any] {
   var isNilOrEmpty: Bool {
       get {
           if let array = self {
              return array.count == 0
           } else {
            return false
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Then I try to use it like this

```
if fetchedResults.fetchedObjects.isNilOrEmpty { ... }
```

I'm getting error

> '[Task]?' is not convertible to 'Optional<[Any]>'

But, by specification

> Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

What is my mistake here? 
Task is subclass of NSManagedObject if it matters.

Comment: Oddly enough if the Core Data API to fetch data is used properly it never returns `nil` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `[Task]` and `[Any]` are two different types, and `Wrapped == [Any]` won't work.

Proper way would be to limit `Wrapped` by protocol, not specific type.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Collection {
    var isNilOrEmpty: Bool {
        get { // `get` can be omitted here, btw
            if let collection = self {
                return collection.isEmpty // Prefer `isEmpty` over `.count == 0`
            } else {
                return true // If it's `nil` it should return `true` too
            }
        }
    }
}
```